# Accessing PHP Class Method in Joomla

Tags: php, class, methods, joomla

There is an example Hello Word component in Joomla.

In Models:

```
class HellowWorldModelHelloWorld extends JModel
{
Protected $message;

Public function getMsg()
{
if (!isset($this->message))
{
$this->message = 'Hello World';
}
return $this->message;
}
}
```

in Views:

```
class HelloWorldViewHelloWorld extends JViewLegacy
{

    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $this->msg = $this->get('Msg');

        if (count($errors=$this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JLog::add(implode('<br/>',$errors),JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }

        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

Now my question is how this works, as far as I have learned, I can't make it out the below code

```
$this->msg = $this->get('Msg');
```

First `$this->msg` - `msg` property is not defined anywhere in the class or in the parent class. So how `msg` is get defined or set by directly accessing `$this->msg`

Second the method in the model is defined as `function getMsg()` . So I think it should be accessible as `$this-getMsg()`(but it doesn't work) but it is being accessed as `$this-get('Msg')` and it is working fine.

A detailed answer with example will help me properly understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how detailed I can make this, but executing `$this->msg = $this->get('Msg`) amounts to executing `function getMsg()` that is located in the model.

So, in your View, `$this->msg = $this->get('Msg')` will populate the *variable* `$this->msg` with *whatever* is returned by the `function getMsg()` in the Model.